# How to use ElasticSearch to bucket historical data from midnight to now?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have an index with timestamps in the following format:

```
2015-03-20T12:00:00+0500
```

What I would like to do in the SQL equivalent is the following:

```
select date(timestamp), sum(orders)
from data
where time(timestamp) < time(now)
group  by date(timestamp)
```

I know I need an aggregation but, for now, I've tried a basic search query below but I'm getting a malformed error:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "query":
            {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter":
            {
                "range":
                {
                   "@timestamp":
                   {
                     "from": "00:00:01.000",
                     "to": "15:00:00.000"
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed want an aggregation, specifically the [date histogram](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) aggregation. Something like

```
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "aggs": {
    "by_date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "order_sum": {
          "sum": {"field": "foo"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First you have a bucketing aggregation that groups your documents by date, then inside that a metric aggregation that computes a value (in this case a sum) for each bucket

which would return data of the form

```
{
   ...

   "aggregations": {
      "by_date": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key": 1425168000000,
               "doc_count": 8644,
               "order_sum": {
                 "value": 1234
               }
            },
            {
               "key_as_string": "2015-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key": 1425254400000,
               "doc_count": 8819,
               "order_sum": {
                 "value": 45678
               }
            }, 
            ...
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

There is a good intro to aggregations on the elasticsearch blog ([part 1](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations) and [part 2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations)) if you want to do some more reading.

Comment: This is great although I don't want the WHOLE day. e.g. I want an aggregation of each day from midnight to a given time (or "now").

Comment: @alexpotato There's no builtin filter that does that to my knowledge - I think you'd need a script filter or to add a field to the index that says that the time of day is in the correct range

Comment: @FrederickCheung, you only show how to aggregate it. May I ask you to show the sample data which is aggregated by that too? Thanks

Comment: @AminahNuraini I don't think it was anything more than documents  with a day field and a foo Field

Comment: @FrederickCheung, then the example will be simple. That's okay, though. Well, in MongoDB, the data is stored as a date string and MongoDB still can process it well. I don't know if ElasticSearch is like that too, so it's best to see a sample.